# Can't get ember bindings to work as documented

Tags: ember.js

I am following the [documentation](http://emberjs.com) on emberjs.com, but can't get the first bindings example to work.

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akLVy/) to demonstrate. What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ember.js uses the concept of a RunLoop to allow bindings, observers and so on.

The problem with the example is that by setting a (bound) property and immediately getting the value via `console.log` no event is fired which would trigger the RunLoop and therefore synchronize the changes. There are 2 excellent blog posts about the RunLoop: [Part 1](http://blog.sproutcore.com/the-run-loop-part-1/) and [Part 2](http://blog.sproutcore.com/the-run-loop-part-2/). Although they target Sproutcore, the concept is about the same for Ember.js.

There are two ways to make your example work.

**Force synchronisation via `Ember.run.sync()`**

As the docs state, invoking `Ember.run.sync()` *... is a useful way to immediately force all  bindings in the application to sync*. This leaves the code like this, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/cwR3P/

```js
App = Ember.Application.create({});
App.wife = Ember.Object.create({
  householdIncome: 80000
});

App.husband = Ember.Object.create({
  householdIncomeBinding: 'App.wife.householdIncome'
});

// force bindings to sync
Ember.run.sync();

console.log(App.husband.get('householdIncome')); // 80000

// Someone gets raise.
App.husband.set('householdIncome', 90000);

// force bindings to sync
Ember.run.sync();

console.log(App.wife.get('householdIncome')); // 90000​
```

---

Or the second option is to ...

**Show the values in a view**

Showing the properties in a view handles all the RunLoop stuff for you, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/Ub97S/

**JavaScript**:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create({});
App.wife = Ember.Object.create({
    householdIncome: 80000
});

App.husband = Ember.Object.create({
    householdIncomeBinding: 'App.wife.householdIncome'
});

// invoke function in 3000ms
Ember.run.later(function() {
    // someone gets a raise
    App.husband.set('householdIncome', 90000);
}, 3000);​
```

**Handlebars** (the view):

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    Wifes income: {{App.wife.householdIncome}}<br/>
    Husbands income: {{App.husband.householdIncome}}
</script>​
```

Comment: With the view, we can also use the Ember.run.sync(), but only one call is then necessary. http://jsfiddle.net/akLVy/10/

Comment: Well done, Clemens - very helpful! I do think we need to explain this in the docs much better. It's not a good introduction for beginners when one of the examples doesn't run "as is".

Comment: Thanks! Dan, I'll completely agree. This needs to be updated in the docs!

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to call `Ember.run.sync();` after setting up your bindings to give Ember's run loop a chance to sync before your log statements. This is a handy technique for testing with Ember as well, but isn't typically needed in Ember apps themselves.